# Why analytics and experience profile missing in Sitecore Experience Management dashboard

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-dms, sitecore9

**Sitecore Experience Platform** missing the Experience Analytics Section and Experience Profile. How to enable them in the installed Sitecore instance.
Is there any reason why they are missing?

Installed version information

```
<information>
<version>
<major>9</major>
<minor>0</minor>
<build>1</build>
<revision>171219</revision>
</version>
<date>December 19, 2017</date>
<title>Sitecore.NET</title>
<company>Sitecore Corporation A/S.</company>
<copyright>
© 2017 Sitecore Corporation A/S. All rights reserved. Sitecore® is a registered trademark of Sitecore Corporation A/S.
</copyright>
</information>
```

Sitecore Experience Management dashboard
[image]

When run my Sitecore instance on https show me "Not Secure" on browser notification. Suppose my instance is **sxa.storefront.com**, try to browser **https://sxa.storefront.com** then get the notification message on the browser as like the following picture.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're likely running Sitecore in CMS-only mode, or your license does not have xDB enabled (https://doc.sitecore.com/users/90/sitecore-experience-platform/en/cms-only-mode-compatibility.html)

Here are the relevant settings: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/the-cms-only-mode-configuration-settings.html

To validate your settings, go to `http://<yourinstance>/Sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` and look for the settings specified above to view their values.

To validate the license, click on the hamburger menu from the content editor:
[image: Sitecore Licenses]

and check for `Sitecore.xDB.Base`
[image: Sitecore xDB License]

Comment: thanks for your valuable effort, my License Terms
Name:Sitecore.xDB.Base,Expiration:Friday, January 1, 2100,Count:1,Version:8

Comment: When run my Sitecore instance on https show me "Not Secure" on browser notification. Suppose my instance is sxa.storefront.com, try to browser https://sxa.storefront.com then get the notification message on browser